# Maximizing bandwidth use in web crawler

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm currently working in a web crawler focused in news websites. But It's taking too long, I believe it's because the script opens one page at the time, scrap it, and then goes to another page. So theres the time to send the request, get the response from the server and all of that. Is there a way in which I can open more then one page per time and maximize the use of my bandwidth?

```
def get_links(url):
    html = urlopen(url)
    bsObj = bs(html)
    for link in bsObj.find_all('a', href=re.compile("^(http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/)(.)*$")):
        if 'href' in link.attrs:
            if link.attrs['href'] not in urls:
                urls.add(link.attrs['href'])
                to_crawl.add(link.attrs['href'])
    if bsObj.find(attrs={'itemprop':'articleBody'}):
        articles.add(url)
        page_append(url)
        print(url)
    urls_crawled.add(url)
```

Comment: What are you currently doing? Scrapy is recommended usually when scraping using python: http://scrapy.org/

Comment: it is possible, show what you have done so far.

Comment: I updated with the part that gets each page!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Your code processes one page at a time and you are not taking advantage of all your bandwidth.
You may want to either use some specific library as mentioned in the comments (scrappy.org) or look into threads. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Be aware that working with threads is not as simple as just launching your code in several threads. You will have to coordinate how they access your `articles` list. You will need to use something thread-safe.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html